# How can I add/move icloud contacts to a group?

Tags: ios, icloud, contacts, group

I see that iCloud can create groups. It appears that other than All Contacts, I only have another group, contacts-other that was created when I imported my addresses (I think via Outlook, which I no longer use).

How can I assign contacts to a group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On iCloud.com, open Contacts.  Then, click on the ribbon with the people icon until the groups appear.  Now, hit the plus icon at the bottom, and name the new group.  Click back on "All Contacts".  Now, simply drag each contact that you want to move into the group.  If you want to select more than one at a time, just hold down the Command key (control key on Windows) and click on each one, then drag them all into the group.

Comment: And for removing from a group when you have the group list at the left and the group on the right, selecting a contact and pressing delete removes it from the group, not All Contacts.

Comment: Also if you have a group selected in the Groups screen and use the gear>Import vCard, it will go into that group directly.

Comment: This is absurdly unintuitive. Also, more to the point, do-not-disturb mode should allow exceptions for individual contacts rather than groups so I didn't have to do this one-person-in-a-group hack to whitelist a contact to begin with.

Comment: Is it possible to do this from the MacOS app?  I'm not allowed to drag an icloud contact into an icloud group; I'm only allowed to do it to a local group.